# alignment of contents in ListView

Tags: android, listview, alignment, adapter

I have a listview and I want some contents to be shown on the left and other contents on the right of the list :
[for example](http://lh3.ggpht.com/l9BfwHuON835jCoyVvFVBSRXTs-kv1Aca3Rb1q4RPeUAvBoNUnd5ZG7mT5scJhmK35rh)

Meaning that the content which

`getItem(position).getIsMO() == false`

to be shown in the left side of the list.And the content which

`getItem(position).getIsMO() == true`

to be shown in the right side of the list.

The code of that part is:

```
    public static class EfficientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>
            implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        // private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<Message> values;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> values) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            super(context, R.layout.mycontent, values);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView1(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
            // unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;
            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
            // no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
            // supplied
            // by ListView is null.

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontent, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                if (getItem(position).getIsMO() == false) {
                    // parent.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
                    // convertView.layout(15, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.body = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.body);
                    holder.date = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.date);
                    holder.from = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.from);
                    holder.status = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.status);
                } else {
                    // convertView.layout(0, 0, 15, 0);
                    // parent.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);

                    holder.body = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.body);
                    holder.date = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.date);
                    holder.from = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.from);
                    holder.status = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.status);
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            holder.body.setText(getItem(position).getBody());
            holder.date.setText(getItem(position).getDate());
            holder.from.setText(getItem(position).getPhoneNumber());
            holder.status
                    .setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).getStatus()));
            /*
             * if ("000".equals(getItem(position).getPhoneNumber())) { //
             * convertView.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0); // View layout =
             * View.inflate(context, R.layout.mycontent, null); //
             * layout.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
             * convertView.setLayoutParams(params); // parent.setPadding(5, 0,
             * 0, 0); } else { // View layout = View.inflate(context,
             * R.layout.mycontent, null); // layout.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
             * parent.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0); // convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 5,
             * 0); }
             */
            return convertView;

        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView from;
            TextView date;
            TextView body;
            TextView status;
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I try the `parent.setPadding()` all the objects align in the listview in one side.

Thank you for your time
mkounal

mycontent1.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/objectscreenmoall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnListener"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fromMO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/phoNum"
            android:textColor="#01acec"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateMO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#01acec"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bodyMO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/body"
            android:textColor="#01acec"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusMO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ringtone_"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/allList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two different XMLs here.

That is when `getItem(position).getIsMO() == false` set first layout like:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontent1, null); // the row with blue background.
```

else

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontent2, null); // the row with green background.
```

Try doing this.

If this doesn't work, we'll find some other solution.

Comment: Shrikant I edited my question. I posted the one from the 2 mycontents and the ListView which calls the mycontents. When I do your way it changes the padding inside the element, but I want to change the whole element size and aligment, what am I doing wrong? ty for your help

Comment: Can you elaborate your ques? I am not getting the scenario exactly. According to my solution, you need to create two different xmls, where in one xml, place all views on the left hand side and in second xml, place all views on right hand side. Once you inflate the correct xml according to your condition, there will not be any need of padding then.

Comment: I created two xml files,mycontent1.xml and mycontent2.xml, they have the same code inside the only difference between them is that I set the margin* in the first on the left and the margin of the second xml on the right using the android:layout_marginLeft=" "    When I call these two files with the inflate method the list show the different elements in the like there is no padding in them,the one after the other like that : ( http://www.thechromesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/android-g1-55.jpg )

Comment: Your way works fine thank you vary much,I just had to add a second LinearLayout in order to do the right margins in the 2 xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use two different row layouts, one with `android:layout_gravity="right"` and one with `android:layout_gravity="left"`.  Then just check for which you need to use in your adapter.